# Which animals live in trees and make noises like rubber ducks at night?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

I was recently at night in a public park in Karlsruhe, Germany. I've heard many (at least 10, probably many more - it's hard to tell) animals in the trees making noises similar to that of a rubber duck which is pressed.

What could that be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is most likely a **Tawny Owl** (*Strix aluco*), or ***Waldkauz*** in German, one of the most common owl species in Central Europe. These owls have many different calls, and you can hear them often here in Karlsruhe at night. Particularly their ["kewick" call](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Tawny_Owl_%28Strix_aluco%29_%28W1CDR0001427_BD9%29.ogg) sounds similar to squeezing a rubber duck. It is usally emitted by female individuals during the mating season, but also males can produce it. Juveniles have a [similar call](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mVavaxmFvk) as well. But most of the time - as far as I have noticed - you only hear their more common "hoo-hoo" calls (listen [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Tawny_Owl_%28Strix_aluco%29_%28W1CDR0001519_BD8%29.ogg) or [here](http://www.deutsche-vogelstimmen.de/waldkauz/)).

Photo of a [Tawny Owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tawny_owl):

[image: Tawny Owl]

**Image Source:**

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Waldkauz-Strix_aluco.jpg

Comment: * Listening to the kewick call and trying to judge whether it really sounds like a rubber duck * ..... mmhh yeah... Ok, that works! +1

Comment: @Remi.b well he said "similar", not "exactly like" :)

Comment: It sounded exactly like the "kewick" call! Thank you! I'm positively surprised that somebody could identify that with this little information :-)

Comment: @MartinThoma Probably because we live in the same town ;)

Comment: @adjan Haha, the world ist small. But we don't know each other, do we?

Comment: I have lived close by, but our Waldkäuze didn't sound like rubber ducks, or our rubber ducks don't sound like Waldkäuze. Now I am confused.

Comment: @MartinThoma No I don't think so.

Comment: Where I live near Vancouver Canada, barred owls can sometimes be heard at night. My older son was convinced that some drunk teenagers were making stupid sounds at night. (Too many noisy drunks lived in the area.) When a bonded pair start caterwauling, they cerainly font sound like owls. Animals can make some very surprising sounds for those not familiar with them!